# How to change links to white on a dark mode

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a dark mode for my site and I encounter this problem, the links can't change their color from black to white however normal text can successfully switch color to white in dark mode. Thanks in advance for the answer!
I cannot post the code for some reason, stackoverflow is not letting me.

Comment: set a class for dark mode and change the link style when that class is active: `.dark-mode .link { /* styles here */ }`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not letting you? probably you have too much code, if you do then you can try to minimize it. Or you are not using code fences to format the code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a specific css selector to change the color of your links. For example if they are still anchor tags you could do something along the lines of:

```
.dark-theme a { color: white; }
```